# How to mock functions in the same module using Jest?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, jestjs

What's the best way to correctly mock the following example?

The problem is that after import time, `foo` keeps the reference to the original unmocked `bar`.

`module.js`:

```
export function bar () {
    return 'bar';
}

export function foo () {
    return `I am foo. bar is ${bar()}`;
}
```

`module.test.js`:

```
import * as module from '../src/module';

describe('module', () => {
    let barSpy;

    beforeEach(() => {
        barSpy = jest.spyOn(
            module,
            'bar'
        ).mockImplementation(jest.fn());
    });


    afterEach(() => {
        barSpy.mockRestore();
    });

    it('foo', () => {
        console.log(jest.isMockFunction(module.bar)); // outputs true

        module.bar.mockReturnValue('fake bar');

        console.log(module.bar()); // outputs 'fake bar';

        expect(module.foo()).toEqual('I am foo. bar is fake bar');
        /**
         * does not work! we get the following:
         *
         *  Expected value to equal:
         *    "I am foo. bar is fake bar"
         *  Received:
         *    "I am foo. bar is bar"
         */
    });
});
```

I could change:

```
export function foo () {
    return `I am foo. bar is ${bar()}`;
}
```

to:

```
export function foo () {
    return `I am foo. bar is ${exports.bar()}`;
}
```

but this is pretty ugly in my opinion to do everywhere.

Comment: See this issue thread on `jest` GH page https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936#issuecomment-545080082

Comment: In 2021, Jest has an official way to do this "partial mocking", that doesn't require modification of the `module.js` code and is straightforward and simple/declarative to write: https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-partials .

Comment: @user3773048 unfortunately, the 'partial mocking' can't work as expected. I tried, but it still failed to work.

Comment: @user3773048 Partial mocking still won't work when the function is called from the module itself

Answer (score 12, accepted):

fwiw, the solution I settled on was to use [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), by setting a default argument.

So I would change

```
export function bar () {
    return 'bar';
}

export function foo () {
    return `I am foo. bar is ${bar()}`;
}
```

to

```
export function bar () {
    return 'bar';
}

export function foo (_bar = bar) {
    return `I am foo. bar is ${_bar()}`;
}
```

This is not a breaking change to the API of my component, and I can easily override bar in my test by doing the following

```
import { foo, bar } from '../src/module';

describe('module', () => {
    it('foo', () => {
        const dummyBar = jest.fn().mockReturnValue('fake bar');
        expect(foo(dummyBar)).toEqual('I am foo. bar is fake bar');
    });
});
```

This has the benefit of leading to slightly nicer test code too :)

Comment: I'm generally not a fan of dependency injection, since you are allowing tests to change how the code is written. That being said, this is better than the current higher-voted answer which is pretty ugly

Comment: nicer test but bad code. Not really a good idea to change your code because you cannot find a way to test it. As a developer when I look at that code, it makes me think 100x times as to why a particular method present in the module passed as a dependency to another method in same module.

Comment: Once you start to create micro apps (extract a specific part of your code into an npm package, eg: utils folder), dependency injection will become your friend. If you combine object destructuring with dependency injection, the code becomes much cleaner.
Another benefit of using here object destructuring with dependency injection is that you'll have a pure function, which is ideal when dealing with functions.

Comment: to @Sean's point, it seems like all the answers here change the way your code is written to make it testable. Of the options, I like this the best too. Using `exports.bar` is especially problematic for TypeScript projects, because you lose out on static typing.

Answer (score 63):

An alternative solution can be importing the module into its own code file and using the imported instance of all of the exported entities. Like this:

```
import * as thisModule from './module';

export function bar () {
    return 'bar';
}

export function foo () {
    return `I am foo. bar is ${thisModule.bar()}`;
}
```

Now mocking `bar` is really easy, because `foo` is also using the exported instance of `bar`:

```
import * as module from '../src/module';

describe('module', () => {
    it('foo', () => {
        spyOn(module, 'bar').and.returnValue('fake bar');
        expect(module.foo()).toEqual('I am foo. bar is fake bar');
    });
});
```

Importing the module into its own code looks strange, but due to the ES6's support for cyclic imports, it works really smoothly.

Comment: This worked for me, with the least impact to existing code, and easy to follow tests.

Comment: This was the easiest route for me as well.

Comment: Very useful. Thank you.

Comment: If you're using Node's ES Modules, in the first line of `module.js`, remember to add `.js` in the import path such that it becomes `import * as thisModule from './module.js';`

Comment: how do I reset the mocks once done

Comment: I get "bar is not declared configurable" when trying this

Comment: I can fix that with using `jest.mock` and `jest.requireActual`, but then I get a second problem: any const defined functions (or variables) will give an error of `Cannot access 'bar' before initialization`

Comment: This is problematic though, since it creates a circular dependency (which makes tree-shaking not work).

Answer (score 49):

The problem seems to be related to how you expect the scope of bar to be resolved.

On one hand, in `module.js` you export two functions (instead of an object holding these two functions). Because of the way modules are exported the reference to the container of the exported things is `exports` like you mentioned it.

On the other hand, you handle your export (that you aliased `module`) like an object holding these functions and trying to replace one of its function (the function bar).

If you look closely at your foo implementation you are actually holding a fixed reference to the bar function.

**When you think you replaced the bar function with a new one you just actually replaced the reference copy in the scope of your module.test.js**

To make foo actually use another version of bar you have two possibilities :

1. In module.js export a class or an instance, holding both the foo and bar method:

   Module.js:

   ```
   export class MyModule {
     function bar () {
       return 'bar';
     }

     function foo () {
       return `I am foo. bar is ${this.bar()}`;
     }
   }
   ```

   *Note the use of **this** keyword in the foo method.*

   Module.test.js:

   ```
   import { MyModule } from '../src/module'

   describe('MyModule', () => {
     //System under test :
     const sut:MyModule = new MyModule();

     let barSpy;

     beforeEach(() => {
         barSpy = jest.spyOn(
             sut,
             'bar'
         ).mockImplementation(jest.fn());
     });


     afterEach(() => {
         barSpy.mockRestore();
     });

     it('foo', () => {
         sut.bar.mockReturnValue('fake bar');
         expect(sut.foo()).toEqual('I am foo. bar is fake bar');
     });
   });
   ```
2. Like you said, rewrite the global reference in the global `exports` container. **This is not a recommended way to go as you will possibly introduce weird behaviors in other tests if you don't properly reset the exports to its initial state.**

Comment: Switching to a class, while it works, still leads to the conclusion that there's no way to fully unit test es6 module functions that reference each other doesn't it?

Comment: the only way i've been able to do it in the past, is to put the functions which depend on each other, in different .js / .ts files. 

i.e FuncA calls FuncB, if FuncA is the function undert test, you would spy on funcB and mock the the return value, however could only get it to work if funcB was in a different file.

Answer (score 11):

Works for me:

```
cat moduleWithFunc.ts

export function funcA() {
 return export.funcB();
}
export function funcB() {
 return false;
}

cat moduleWithFunc.test.ts

import * as module from './moduleWithFunc';

describe('testFunc', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    module.funcB.mockRestore();
  });

  it.only('testCase', () => {
    // arrange
    jest.spyOn(module, 'funcB').mockImplementationOnce(jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true));

    // act
    const result = module.funcA();

    // assert
    expect(result).toEqual(true);
    expect(module.funcB).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: This does not work for me. funcB is never called.

Answer (score 10):

I had this same problem and due to the project's linting standards, defining a class or rewriting references in the `exports` were not code review approvable options even if not prevented by the linting definitions. What I stumbled on as a viable option is to use the [babel-rewire-plugin](https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire/) which is much cleaner, at least in appearance. While I found this used in another project I had access to, I noticed it was already in an answer in a similar question which I have linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45645229/6867420). This is a snippet adjusted for this question (and without using spies) provided from the linked answer for reference (I also added semicolons in addition to removing spies because I'm not a heathen):

```js
import __RewireAPI__, * as module from '../module';

describe('foo', () => {
  it('calls bar', () => {
    const barMock = jest.fn();
    __RewireAPI__.__Rewire__('bar', barMock);
    
    module.foo();

    expect(bar).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45645229/6867420

Comment: This should be accepted answer. The plugin just works && there is zero need to rewrite any code outside of the test. TY

Comment: Thanks for this, if you're in a babel environment then this is the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 9):

From this [thread](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936#issuecomment-545080082):

Try using a function expression

```
export const bar = () => {
  return "bar"
}
```

This should let you spy on `bar` even if its used by another function in the same module.

Comment: Note ALL functions involved must be refactored into arrow functions.

Comment: I get the error "[the function] is not declared configurable" when trying this

Comment: For me, arrow notation still not works...

Answer (score 1):

If you define your exports you can then reference your functions as part of the exports object. Then you can overwrite the functions in your mocks individually. This is due to how the import works as a reference, not a copy.

> module.js:

```
exports.bar () => {
    return 'bar';
}

exports.foo () => {
    return `I am foo. bar is ${exports.bar()}`;
}
```

> module.test.js:

```
describe('MyModule', () => {

  it('foo', () => {
    let module = require('./module')
    module.bar = jest.fn(()=>{return 'fake bar'})

    expect(module.foo()).toEqual('I am foo. bar is fake bar');
  });

})
```

Comment: I like this, but for me it blows up in the production bundle.`exports is undefiend`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Babel (i.e. `@babel/parser`) to handle transpiling your code, the [`babel-plugin-explicit-exports-references`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-explicit-exports-references)<sup>1</sup> npm package solves this pretty elegantly by making the "ugly" `module.exports` replacements for you *transparently at transpile time*. See [the original problem thread](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936#issuecomment-821944391) for more information.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note: I wrote this plugin!

Answer (score 0):

Given the following file structure

```
export const A = () => 'A';
export const B = () => 'B';
export const C = () => A() + ' ' + B();
```

The tests can look like

```
import {A, B, C} from './module';
describe('module', () => {
    test('it returns A', () => expect(A()).toEqual('A'))
    test('it returns B', () => expect(B()).toEqual('B'))
    test('it returns A + B', () => {
        const module = jest.requireActual('./module');
        module.A = jest.fn().mockReturnValue('AA');
        module.B = jest.fn().mockReturnValue('BB')
        expect(module.C()).toEqual('AA BB');
        expect(module.B).toHaveBeenCalledExactlyOnceWith();
        expect(module.C).toHaveBeenCalledExactlyOnceWith();
    })
})
```

Using this approach you can also easily change/mock the behaviour of the other functions.

Answer (score -1):

For **CommonJS modules** users, suppose the file looks something like:

```js
/* myModule.js */
function bar() {
  return "bar";
}

function foo() {
  return `I am foo. bar is ${bar()}`;
}

module.exports = { bar, foo };
```

You need to modify the file to:

```js
/* myModule.js */
function bar() {
  return "bar";
}

function foo() {
  return `I am foo. bar is ${myModule.bar()}`;  // Change `bar()` to `myModule.bar()`
}

const myModule = { bar, foo };  // Items you wish to export

module.exports = myModule;  // Export the object
```

Your original test suite (`myModule.test.js`) should now pass:

```js
const myModule = require("./myModule");

describe("myModule", () => {
  test("foo", () => {
    jest.spyOn(myModule, "bar").mockReturnValueOnce("bar-mock");

    const result = myModule.foo();
    expect(result).toBe("I am foo. bar is bar-mock");
  });
});
```

Read more: [Mock/Spy exported functions within a single module in Jest](https://medium.com/@DavideRama/mock-spy-exported-functions-within-a-single-module-in-jest-cdf2b61af642)

Comment: doesn't seem to work

Answer (score -1):

There are various hacks available here to make this work, but the real answer most people should be using is: don't. Taking the OP's example module:

```
export function bar () {
    return 'bar';
}

export function foo () {
    return `I am foo. bar is ${bar()}`;
}
```

and testing the *actual behaviour*, you'd write:

```
import { bar, foo } from "path/to/module";

describe("module", () => {
    it("foo returns 'bar'", () => {
        expect(bar()).toBe('bar');
    });

    it("foo returns 'I am foo. bar is bar'", () => {
        expect(foo()).toBe('I am foo. bar is bar');
    });
});
```

Why? Because then you can refactor inside the module boundary without changing the tests, which gives you the confidence to improve the quality of your code in the knowledge that it still does what it's supposed to.

Imagine you extracted the creation of `'bar'` from `bar` to an unexported function, for example:

```
function rawBar() {
    return 'bar';
}

export function bar () {
    return rawBar();
}

export function foo () {
    return `I am foo. bar is ${rawBar()}`;
}
```

The test I suggest above would pass. If you'd asserted that calling `foo` meant `bar` got called, that test would start failing, even though the refactor preserved the module's behaviour (same API, same outputs). That's an *implementation detail*.

Test doubles are for *collaborators*, if something really does need to be mocked here it should be extracted to a separate module (then mocking it is much easier, which tells you you're moving in the right direction). Trying to mock functions in the same module is like mocking parts of a class you're trying to test, which I illustrate similarly here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66752334/3001761.

Comment: This is all nice until your inner function is an API call that you want to mock response for. Then your proposed solution doesn't work. It has been documented as an issue (somehow closed without resolving) in Jest project https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6972

Comment: @codeepic _"if something really does need to be mocked here it should be extracted to a separate module"_

Comment: (Also in general the idea that Jest could or should provide a test boundary inside a module like this is, as well as bad test/design practice, a misunderstanding of how the functions access one another _at the JavaScript level_. It's not something Jest controls.)