# What is the state of the art for testing/mocking functions within a module in 2018?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, babel-jest

I have a module, for the purposes of learning testing, that looks like this:

**api.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";
const URI_USERS = 'users/';

export async function makeApiCall(uri) {
    try {
        const response = await axios(BASE_URL + uri);
        return response.data;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err.message;
    }
}

export async function fetchUsers() {
    return makeApiCall(URI_USERS);
}

export async function fetchUser(id) {
    return makeApiCall(URI_USERS + id);
}

export async function fetchUserStrings(...ids) {
    const users = await Promise.all(ids.map(id => fetchUser(id)));
    return users.map(user => parseUser(user));
}

export function parseUser(user) {
    return `${user.name}:${user.username}`;
}
```

Pretty straight forward stuff.

Now I want to test that `fetchUserStrings` method, and to do that I want to mock/spy on both `fetchUser` and `parseUser`. At the same time - I don't want the behaviour of `parseUser` to stay mocked - for when I'm actually testing that.

I run in the problem that it seems that it is not possible to mock/spy on functions within the same module.

Here are the resources I've read about it:

[How to mock a specific module function? Jest github issue.](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936)  (100+ thumbs up).

where we're told:

> Supporting the above by mocking a function after requiring a module is impossible in JavaScript – there is (almost) no way to retrieve the binding that foo refers to and modify it.
>
> The way that jest-mock works is that it runs the module code in isolation and then retrieves the metadata of a module and creates mock functions. Again, in this case it won't have any way to modify the local binding of foo.

### Refer to the functions via an object

The solution he proposes is ES5 - but the modern equivalent is described in this blog post:

https://luetkemj.github.io/170421/mocking-modules-in-jest/

Where, instead of calling my functions directly, I refer to them via an object like:

**api.js**

```
async function makeApiCall(uri) {
    try {
        const response = await axios(BASE_URL + uri);
        return response.data;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err.message;
    }
}

async function fetchUsers() {
    return lib.makeApiCall(URI_USERS);
}

async function fetchUser(id) {
    return lib.makeApiCall(URI_USERS + id);
}

async function fetchUserStrings(...ids) {
    const users = await Promise.all(ids.map(id => lib.fetchUser(id)));
    return users.map(user => lib.parseUser(user));
}

function parseUser(user) {
    return `${user.name}:${user.username}`;
}

const lib = {
    makeApiCall, 
    fetchUsers, 
    fetchUser, 
    fetchUserStrings, 
    parseUser
}; 

export default lib;
```

Other posts that suggest this solution:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sinonjs/bPZYl6jjMdg
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45288360/1068446

And this one seems to be a variant of the same idea:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47976589/1068446

### Break the object into modules

An alternative, is that I would break my module up, such that I'm never calling functions directly within each other.

eg.

**api.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";

export async function makeApiCall(uri) {
    try {
        const response = await axios(BASE_URL + uri);
        return response.data;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err.message;
    }
}
```

**user-api.js**

```
import {makeApiCall} from "./api"; 

export async function fetchUsers() {
    return makeApiCall(URI_USERS);
}

export async function fetchUser(id) {
    return makeApiCall(URI_USERS + id);
}
```

**user-service.js**

```
import {fetchUser} from "./user-api.js"; 
import {parseUser} from "./user-parser.js"; 

export async function fetchUserStrings(...ids) {
    const users = await Promise.all(ids.map(id => lib.fetchUser(id)));
    return ids.map(user => lib.parseUser(user));
}
```

**user-parser.js**

```
export function parseUser(user) {
    return `${user.name}:${user.username}`;
}
```

And that way I can mock the dependency modules when I'm testing the dependant module, no worries.

But I'm not sure that breaking up the modules like this is even feasible - I imagine that there might be a circumstance where you have circular dependencies.

There are some alternatives:

### Dependency injection in the function:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47804180/1068446

This one looks ugly as though, imo.

### Use babel-rewire plugin

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52725067/1068446

I have to admit - I haven't looked at this much.

### Split your test into multiple files

Am investigating this one now.

My question: **This is all quite a frustrating and fiddly way of testing - is there a standard, nice and easy, way people are writing unit tests in 2018, that specifically solve this issue?**

Answer (score 2):

As you've already discovered attempting to directly test an ES6 module is extremely painful. In your situation it sounds like you are transpiling the ES6 module rather than testing it directly, which would likely generate code that looks something like this:

```
async function makeApiCall(uri) {
    ...
}

module.exports.makeApiCall = makeApiCall;
```

Since the other methods are calling `makeApiCall` directly, rather than the export, even if you tried to mock the export nothing would happen. As it stands ES6 module exports are immutable, so even if you did not transpile the module you would likely still have issues.

---

Attaching everything to a "lib" object is probably the easiest way to get going, but it feels like a hack, not a solution. Alternatively using a library that can rewire the module is a potential solution, but its extremely hokey and in my opinion it smells. Usually when you're running into this type of code smell you have a design problem.

Splitting up the modules into tiny pieces feels like a poor mans dependency injection, and as you've stated you'll likely run into issues quickly. Real dependency injection is probably the most robust solution, but it's something you need to build from the ground up, it's not something that you can just plug into an existing project and expect to have things working immediately.

---

My suggestion? Create classes and use them for testing instead, then just make the module a thin wrapper over an instance of the class. Since you're using a class you'll always be referencing your method calls using a centralized object (the `this` object) which will allow you to mock out the things you need. Using a class will also give you an opportunity to inject data when you construct the class, giving you extremely fine grained control in your tests.

Let's refactor your `api` module to use a class:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export class ApiClient {
    constructor({baseUrl, client}) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
        this.client = client;
    }

    async makeApiCall(uri) {
        try {
            const response = await this.client(`${this.baseUrl}${uri}`);
            return response.data;
        } catch (err) {
            throw err.message;
        }
    }

    async fetchUsers() {
        return this.makeApiCall('/users');
    }

    async fetchUser(id) {
        return this.makeApiCall(`/users/${id}`);
    }

    async fetchUserStrings(...ids) {
        const users = await Promise.all(ids.map(id => this.fetchUser(id)));
        return users.map(user => this.parseUser(user));
    }

    parseUser(user) {
        return `${user.name}:${user.username}`;
    }
}

export default new ApiClient({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/",
    client: axios
});
```

Now lets create some tests for the `ApiClient` class:

```
import {ApiClient} from './api';

describe('api tests', () => {

    let api;
    beforeEach(() => {
        api = new ApiClient({
            baseUrl: 'http://test.com',
            client: jest.fn()
        });
    });

    it('makeApiCall should use client', async () => {
        const response = {data: []};
        api.client.mockResolvedValue(response);
        const value = await api.makeApiCall('/foo');
        expect(api.client).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://test.com/foo');
        expect(value).toBe(response.data);
    });

    it('fetchUsers should call makeApiCall', async () => {
        const value = [];
        jest.spyOn(api, 'makeApiCall').mockResolvedValue(value);
        const users = await api.fetchUsers();
        expect(api.makeApiCall).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/users');
        expect(users).toBe(value);
    });
});
```

I should note that I have not tested if the provided code works, but hopefully the concept is clear enough.

Comment: Thanks for a good quality answer. Would the problem with this solution - is that it would remove any ability to do tree shaking? ie. what if your module instead was some kind of lodash library, and you only wanted to use that one `parseUsers` function.

Comment: I suppose if you're building utility functions that *should* be completely decoupled then separating everything into different modules would be ideal. (ie. do what lodash does...)