# Jest: How to mock one specific function when using module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm trying to mock one specific function when using module.exports. How could I test the inner function B?

In my worker.js

```
module.exports = function () {
  this.funcA = funcA
  this.funcB = funcB
}

funcA () {
  funcB()
}

funcB() {...}
```

In my worker-test.js

```
const Worker = require('./worker')

test('test functionB', () => {...}) 

test('test functionA', () => {
  const work = new Worker()
  work.funcB = jest.fn()  //mock funcB
  work.funcA  //run funcA

  expect(work.funcB).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) //Error
})
```

I'm new to jest. Is there any good way to mock function in this case?

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules

Comment: @Dom I have read this, but i still have no idea in my case. :(

Comment: @Dom - That doesn't help. This is a common problem.

Comment: I went through this a while back. If you're interested - I summarised some things here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53736766/what-is-the-state-of-the-art-for-testing-mocking-functions-within-a-module-in-20

Comment: And see the accepted answer for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54318830/why-does-mutating-a-module-update-the-reference-if-calling-that-module-from-anot

Comment: @dwjohnston Thanks for these helpful links. The summarised one is very clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to mock `funcB` the way the code is currently written since `funcA` calls `funcB` directly.

The easiest way to fix it is to note that `worker.js` returns a constructor function and `funcA` and `funcB` are *almost* [prototype methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Prototype_methods)...

...if you make them prototype methods then `funcB` can be mocked:

worker.js

```
class Worker {
  funcA() {
    this.funcB();
  }
  funcB() {
    throw new Error('should not make it here');
  }
}

module.exports = Worker;
```

worker.test.js

```
const Worker = require('./worker');

test('test functionB', () => { /* ... */ })

test('test functionA', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(Worker.prototype, 'funcB');  // <= spy on funcB
  spy.mockImplementation(() => {});  // <= mock funcB

  const work = new Worker();
  work.funcA();  // <= call funcA

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);  // Success!
  spy.mockRestore();  // <= restore funcB
})
```

Comment: I try to break all my function into modules. Small module is easy to mock, but I think that I should rewrite my worker.js with class. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I thought I would chime in as I was searching for a way to do this as well and have discovered it is in fact possible.

Rather than calling the javascript function as above, you'll need to give it the scope of `this` to ensure that when you mock `funcB`, `funcA` calls the mocked version rather than just the function itself.

This means `worker.js` becomes

```js
module.exports = function () {
  this.funcA = funcA
  this.funcB = funcB
}

funcA () {
  this.funcB()
}

funcB() {/* Your impl */}
```

And `worker.test.js` can remain, as before:

```js
const Worker = require('./worker')

test('test functionB', () => {...}) 

test('test functionA', () => {
  // You could even just have: const work = require('./worker')
  const work = new Worker()
  work.funcB = jest.fn()  //mock funcB
  work.funcA()  //run funcA

  expect(work.funcB).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```