# How to mock all but one method of a javascript class using jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I mock a javascript class in a file using `jest.mock('./blabla.js')`. The file `blabla.js` exports a new instance of the class when imported per default (`export default new BlaBla()`). That class has several methods in it. I want to use original implementation of just one (or some) of these methods, but I want to continue using mocks of other methods. Is it ever possible on jest?

There is a similar question asked for nodejs here: [Jest: How to mock one specific function when using module.exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55821609/jest-how-to-mock-one-specific-function-when-using-module-exports). But if I tried to adapt this solution to my test spec, it simply didn't work.

Comment: Either the BlaBla instance is a collaborator that should be replaced with a test double or part of the implementation that shouldn't. Don't go halves; split it into separate components, if the different treatment is really needed.

Comment: Why the solution didn't work? Show the code to reproduce your issue and the error you got.

Comment: You can mock specific methods on class `prototype`, this doesn't require the use of jest.mock.