# Jest - when using spyOn function ensure the spied one is not called

Tags: javascript, angular, jestjs

From Jest notes: **Note: By default, jest.spyOn also calls the spied method.**

In my Angular component.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.offsetPopoverPosition();
}
```

In my spec:

```
it('ngAfterViewInit() method should call offsetPopoverPosition() method', () => {
    const mockListener = jest.spyOn(cmp, 'offsetPopoverPosition');
    const spy = mockListener.mockImplementation(() => {
      console.log('in the mock');
    });

    cmp.ngAfterViewInit();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Simple. Yet the original function is still being called.
I checked Jest 23.x docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/23.x/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/23.x/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn

And few examples on the internets but I can't prevent jest from calling the original `offsetPopoverPosition()` method.

Any ideas?

I am cross linking to Jest github issue which is for some reason closed without resolving it.

[Jest spyOn() calls the actual function instead of the mocked](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6972)

Comment: Is `offsetPopoverPosition` bound to `this` in the component constructor?

Comment: No, it's  called only in ngAfterViewInit

Comment: ...ah, looks like `cmp` is an instance so it wouldn't make a difference anyway.  From what I can see of your code it looks like it should work.  (The reason why JonathanHolvey's code in the github link doesn't work is because `processVisit` is calling `saveVisit` directly so mocking the module export for `saveVisit` doesn't have any effect...that doesn't apply to your code since both of your functions are class methods from what I can see)

Comment: For me, it was an issue with modules/importing/exporting and scope/name resolution. This explanation here helped clarify things for me as a newbie to JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45288360/7466271

Answer (score 4):

From my experience, the issue is you're resetting the original mock's intent. When you create a spy, it has its own implementation, by overriding it with mockImplementation, I've experienced the scenario you are describing - instead,  try this:

```
cmp.offsetPopoverPosition = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      console.log('in the mock');
    });
const mockListener = jest.spyOn(cmp, 'offsetPopoverPosition');
// ... do work
expect(mockListener).toHaveBeenCalled[Times,With]()
```

also this assumes that `cmp` is an instance of the component and not just it's definition reference

edit: please note that mocking out a messaged function inside of the component you are testing is a misguided approach to unit testing. Instead of testing communication to the `sameComponent.method` - test any messaging that chained method uses **outside of the component being tested** - With the brief question content, please ignore the testing approach advice I've given if its reading tea leaves and not relevant to your unit test design(s)

Comment: If so, then what is the point of `mockImplementation` provided by the spyInstance object returned by `spyOn`? Also, in your example, you're NOT mocking the original offsetPopoverPosition()` in the original `cmp`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/6972#issuecomment-511015504), the only thing that ended up working for me was to call the target function from the import of the same file. Something like this in React.

```
// cmp.js
import * as thisModule from './cmp';

offsetPopoverPosition = () => {}

ngAfterViewInit = () => {
  thisModule.offsetPopoverPosition();
}
```

It's a weird issue...

The optimal solution does seem to just avoid this scenario by testing other items however (see this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58637912/8285811)).