# How to use jest.spyOn with functional react component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test if the `handleAddBookToCart function` is called when I clicked on the button using `Jest.spyOn`.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
const HomeComponent = props => {
    const { addBookToCart } = props;

    const handleAddBookToCart = id => {
       addBookToCart(id);
    };

    return (
        <button onClick={() => handleAddBookToCart(id)}></button>
    )
}

//Container
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    addBookToCart: idBook => dispatch(cartOperations.addBookToCart(idBook))
});

//file test
describe('Test home component', () => {
   let container;
   let wrapper;
   let component;

   beforeEach(() => {
       wrapper = mount(
           <Provider store={store}>
               <HomeContainer />
           </Provider>
    );
    container = wrapper.find(HomeContainer);
    component = container.find(HomeComponent);

it('calls the handleAddBookToCart function when the button is clicked', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(???)
    component.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: addBookToCart what it does exactly? ajax request or just javascript stuff?

Comment: no it is a simple redux action

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spying on React functional component method with jest and enzyme; Cannot spyOn on a primitive value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58598995/spying-on-react-functional-component-method-with-jest-and-enzyme-cannot-spyon-o)

Answer (score 2):

Should you must use `spyOn`? You can just pass a jest mock fn as the `addBookToCart` prop

```
it('calls the handleAddBookToCart function when the button is clicked', () => {
   const props = {
     addBookToCart: jest.fn(),
     ...your other props
   }
   const component = shallow(<HomeComponent {...props} />)
    component.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(props.addBookToCart).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have another problem, How I can pass props and overwrite that coming from container connect.
I have updated my request

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to send a mock into the property addBookToCart and spy on that when the button is clicked.

So when you create/mount/shallow your component for the unit test, try the following (mount coming from enzyme but feel free to use your existing method of testing components):

```
const spy = jest.fn();
const component = mount(<HomeComponent addBookToCart={spy} />);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have another problem, How I can pass props and overwrite that coming from container connect.
I have updated my request

Comment: I've always found it to be good practice to just export the base class without the connect applied and test that. That way i have full control over props to help test all scenarios and I'm not retesting redux's code.