# Is there a way to test a mocked function then the actual in the same test file on Jest?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs

In the same test file, I need to test the actual redux action creator and then, later, if the same action creator was called from another function.

If I `jest.mock` I'm unable to test the actual. If I don't, I can't mock it later.
I've also tried `jest.spyOn` with `mockImplementation` but it doesn't seem to mock it.

```
// actionsOne.js
export const myActionOne = ({
  type: 'MY_ACTION_ONE'
})

// test.js
import { dispatch } from './reduxStore.js'
import { myActionOne } from './actionsOne.js'
import { myActionTwo } from './actionsTwo.js'

jest.mock('./actionsOne.js', () => ({
  myActionOne: jest.fn()
}))

test('expectation 1', () => {
  // would pass if no mocking is in place. fail otherwise.
  expect(dispatch(myActionOne())).toEqual({
    type: 'MY_ACTION_ONE'
  })
})

test('expectation 2', () => {
  dispatch(myActionTwo()) // say this would also dispatch myActionOne somewhere
  // would pass if mocking is in place. fail otherwise.
  expect(myActionOne).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Because `myActionOne` does a lot of stuff when dispatched, I wanted to test it once and for `myActionTwo` just check if it was called.

Any recommendation? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock functions in the same module using jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111198/how-to-mock-functions-in-the-same-module-using-jest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it to work using `jest.requireActual()`:

```
test('expectation 1', () => {
  const { myActionOne: myActionOneActual } = jest.requireActual('./actionsOne.js')

  expect(dispatch(myActionOneActual())).toEqual({
    type: 'MY_ACTION_ONE'
  })
})
```

**expectation 1** passes because we are asserting with the *actual* function.

No changes to **expectation 2**, since it asserts with the mocked function.