# How to mock functions called within the test function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have module that contains several functions (`foo`, `bar`, etc).

```
// moduleA.js

const someModule = require('someModule')


const moduleA = () => {
   const bar = (param1, param2) => {
     // some implementation
   }

   const foo = (params) => {
    // some implementation
    bar(1, 2)
   }

   return Object.assign({}, someModule, {
      foo,
      bar
   })
}

module.exports = moduleA
```

What I want to do is to mock other module functions (`bar`) being called within my current test (`foo`) function.

```
// jest test file
describe('Testing foo, mocking bar', () => {
    const checker = moduleA()

    it.only('When this, then that', async () => {
        // THIS IS NOT WORKING
        const spy = jest.spyOn(checker, "bar").mockReturnValue("XXXX")


        const response = await checker.foo({ 1, 2, 3})
        expect(response).toBeDefined()
    })
})
```

What is the correct way to spy or stub the `bar` function so that I can mock the results and only focus testing the `foo` functionality?

Comment: The correct way is _not_ to replace `bar` with a test double, it's part of the thing you're supposed to be testing. The fact that `foo` internally calls `bar` is an _implementation detail_ that could be extracted by a subsequent refactor (examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66752334/3001761) - test the _behaviour_ you want. Also note `foo` doesn't actually seem to return anything so whatever the implementation of `bar`, real or otherwise, the assertion `.toBeDefined()` will fail.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's a good rule in general. But there are many cases where you can't do this. For instance, a unit test should never ever read from a database or make an HTTP request. Anything that is outside the scope of your unit needs to be mocked even if it is buried in the stack.

Comment: @Jordan yes, of course there are going to be interactions that you want to replace with test doubles. But that doesn't mean it's appropriate to put test boundaries _inside_ module boundaries. When you have databases and requests, _extract them_ from the business logic you're unit testing using e.g. repository patterns, to give a collaborator you can mock _without_ breaking encapsulation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock functions in the same module using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111198/how-to-mock-functions-in-the-same-module-using-jest)

Comment: Specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761, not the tide of Max Power answers