# How To Mock a Function Call Inside a Module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to understand how to mock a `function` call inside a module when function returns an object, say I have a file

`Sample.ts`

```
export function food(){
  return new Fruit();
}
export function taste(){
  return food().getTaste();
}
```

Now let's say I am trying to test a scenario wether `taste()` throws an error when `getTaste()` throws an error.

I understand I can take advantage of "ES6 module cyclic dependency" to import the module into itself as:

```
import * as sample from './sample';

export function food(){
  return new Fruit();
}
export function taste(){
  return sample.food().getTaste();
}
```

But I am not sure while testing how do I return mocked Fruit `mockedReturnValue` does not allow a "Argument of type 'typeof jest'"

```
const mockedFruit = jest.mock("./fruit", () => ({
    getTaste: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
         throw new Error("Test Error");
    }),
    promise: jest.fn()
}));

test('taste', () => {
  const sample = require('./sample');
  jest.spyOn(sample, 'food').mockReturnValue(mockedFruit);
  expect(sample.taste()).toThrowError();
})
```

Comment: You don't. That's an implementation detail, treat the module boundary as the interface and test its _behaviour_.

Comment: You still want cohesive components and should be testing through the public API, whatever level you're testing at. It's the same reason you don't test private methods. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66752334/3001761 for examples of the issues you get when you test too much at the implementation level - it _prevents_ you from refactoring to improve your code.