# Is it possible to mock inner function call?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

Let's imagine I have a module as below:

```js
// utils.ts
function innerFunction() {
  return 28;
}

function testing() {
  return innerFunction();
}

export {testing}
```

I would like to write a unit test to test `testing` and just mock return value of `innerFunction`, expecting that any call to `innerFunction` will just resolve to a certain value, something like below:

```js
jest.mock('../utils', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('../utils');

  return {
    // __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    innerFunction: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(33),
  };
});

import { testing } from '../utils';

  it('should be okay', () => {
    expect(testing()).toBe(33);
  });
```

I was expecting `jest.requireActual` will be able to read all functions and `innerFunction: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(33)` will actually cause any `innerFunction` invocation to just return `33` as value, but from the little experiment as above it seems like it's not the case.

In actual call `innerFunction` will be returning `28`, but in Jest environment I would like `innerFunction` to be able to resolve to any value that I would like to

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock functions in the same module using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111198/how-to-mock-functions-in-the-same-module-using-jest)

Comment: But the real answer is: you _shouldn't_ like to. Respect the module boundary or move it, test _behaviour_ not implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

Try to pass **innerFunction** as a dependency of **testing**

#### utils.ts

```
function testing(innerFunction: () => number)  {
  return () => innerFunction();
}

export {testing}
```

#### test.ts

```
import { testing } from '../utils'  
  it('should be okay', () => {
    const mock = () => 33

    // AKA System under test
    const sut = testing(mock)

    expect(sut()).toBe(33);
  });
```

Tests can be more simple without jest, and more predictable too...

## Option 2

Move **innerFunction** to another file, and use **jest.mock**

#### innerFunction.ts

```
export function innerFunction()  {
      return 33
}
```

#### utils.ts

```
import { innerFunction } from './innerFunction.ts'

function testing()  {
    return innerFunction();
}

export { testing }
```

#### test.ts

```
jest.mock('./innerFunction', () => {
  return () => 33
});

import { testing } from '../utils'

  it('should be okay', () => {
    expect(testing()).toBe(33);
  });
```

Comment: There is another option, you should move "innerFunction" to another file and use jest.mock to import "innerFunction"