# Why does jest mock test give me undefined?

Tags: jestjs, mocking

I am new to learning jest mocks. I am trying out a very simple test. I have a folder greeter. This folder has a file 'greeter.js' and a subfolder called '**test**'. The '**test**' folder has a test called greeter.test.js. Here is the code

greeter.js

```
function greet(fname, lname) {
    return "hello " + greetWithName(fname, lname)
}

export function greetWithName(fname, lname) {
    return fname + " : " + lname
}
 
export default greet
```

and the test is:

```
import greet, {greetWithName} from '../greeter'

jest.mock("../greeter")

describe('checks greeter module', () => {
    it ('greet', () => {
        greetWithName.mockReturnValue("hero");
        expect(greet("a", "b")).toBe("hello hero") // fails
    })
})
```

Curios why expect(**greet**("a", "b")).toBe("hello hero") fails, it is undefined. Not sure why ?

When checked for expect(**greetWithName**("a", "b")).toBe("hero") : passes !!

Comment: Duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111198/how-to-mock-functions-in-the-same-module-using-jest

Answer (score 1):

`jest.mock('../greeter')` is mocking the whole `greeter.js` module, and since you don't provide a `mockReturnValue` for `greet` it's returning `undefined`.

By default, `jest.mock` mocks all exports from a module to return `undefined` unless you provide mock return values. You're mocking `greetWithName` to return a value, but `greet` is also being mocked.

To get the behavior you want, you could either move `greet` into a separate module (which you don't mock), or use [`jest.requireActual`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename) to mock certain functions in a module but not others.