# When writing testable code, should all of a functions sub-functions be passed as callbacks?

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs

I'm using jest to test code in a nodejs server. I'm trying to figure out the best way to write the code for integration tests. It seems like jest's mock function necessitates that any sub-function that a function uses should be passed in as a callback.

For example:

```js
async function apiFunction(){
  return await apiCall();
};

async function subFunction1(){
  return await apiFunction();
};

mainFunction(){
  return await subFunction1();
};
```

Would be better written as:

```js
async function apiFunction(){
  return await apiCall();
};

async function subFunction1(apiFunctionAsCallback){ // all sub-functions passed as a callback
  return await apiFunctionAsCallback();
};

mainFunction(){
  return await subFunction1(apiFunction); // passed as a callback
};
```

Is this generally a better practice for all code? Only I've not seen this pattern much previously and I'm wondering if there are alternative testing packages to jest that handle this differently?

Comment: Are you trying to ask https://stackoverflow.com/q/45111198/3001761? I would (and [did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761)) recommend: don't, particularly if you're calling these _integration_ tests.

Comment: Yeah that actually answers it, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

As per @jonrsharpe's guidance, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47976589/11664580) advises the issue can be solved by exporting the sub-function and then mocking it via jest's [mocking modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules) feature. There's a good example in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47976589/11664580).