# Jest doesn't mock function either through jest.fn or spyOn

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have the following module in my codebase:

```js
const getSomething = () => new SomeThirdPartyCall();

const doSomethingElse = () => {
  const foo = getSomething();
  foo.bar();
};

const someService = { getSomething, doSomethingElse };

export { somethingService };
```

The way export works is to preserve service name in the calls, i.e. `somethingService.doSomethingElse` call will always be consistent across the app.

Now I'm trying to test `doSomethingElse` method and mocking `getSomething` to avoid calling 3rd party lib but it just doesn't work and still calls that 3rd party. What I tried:

```js
somethingService.doSomethingElse = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(); // doesnt work

const doSomethingElseMock = jest.spyOn(somethingService, 'doSomethingElse');
doSomethingElseMock.mockReturnValueOnce() // doesnt work
doSomethingElseMock.mockImplementationOnce() // doesnt work
```

What did I miss and why it's not mocking the function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock functions in the same module using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111198/how-to-mock-functions-in-the-same-module-using-jest)

Comment: _(Specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761, which is to say: don't.)_