# Mocking a function dependency in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Let's imagine to functions, `a` and `b`.

```
function a() {
    return 5;
}

function b() {
    return a() + 5;
}

module.exports = { a, b };
```

To properly test `b`, I want to mock `a`. To do this, I try `jest.mock`:

```
const { a, b } = require("./myFunctions");

jest.mock("./myFunctions", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("./myFunctions"),
  a: jest.fn(() => 10),
}));

describe("myFunctions", () => {
  it("mocks a", () => {
    expect(a()).toEqual(10);
  });

  it("mock affects b", () => {
    expect(b()).toEqual(15);
  });
});
```

The first test succeeds: `a` returns 10 instead of 5 as expected. However, the latter test fails because when `b` calls `a`, it still returns 5.

How do I mock `a` so that it's effective in `b` calls?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761

Comment: Duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111198/how-to-mock-functions-in-the-same-module-using-jest