# How to spyOn a function from the same module in jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ts-jest

Consider this set of code snippets where I want to write unit tests for `function A`, which internally calls `function B` during execution. Assume `B` is a set of API calls for validation that I want to mock return value to true.

But this `spyOn` method approach does not work, and the API calls in `B` still get executed. I've seen approaches with mocking the complete module with `jest.requireActual()`, but they do not seem to work too.

What could be a better way to test such functions without changing a lot in the codebase `index.ts`?

```js
//index.ts

async function A (a:string, b:string, c:string) {
// code 
 await B(data);
// code
}

async function B (data:customType) {
  //code 
  //API calls
  //code 
}

export default {
A,
B }
```

```js
//index.test.ts

import index from '../index.ts'; 

describe('Test suit', ()=>{

  it('should be a test for function A', async ()=> {
    
    jest.spyOn(index, 'B').mockReturnValue(true); 
    // code 
    const result = await index.A('a','b','c');
    // code
  })
})
```

Comment: _(Specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761, TL;DR don't.)_

Answer (score -1):

There is not really a good way to do it, when the functions are in the same module with jest only.

But you can with `Rewire`, it's explained in this answer and worked very well in a similar situation for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52725067/16068019

Otherwise if it's an option you could move one of your functions to a different module, but that's not always an option.