# How to provide mock implementation to redux thunks?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, thunk

How can we mock implementation for redux thunks.

I have thunks in a file:- `src/actions.js`

```
export const getRequest = () => async dispatch => {
    return await dispatch(
            fetchRequestInfo(),
        );
};

export const getBanks = () => async dispatch => {
    const response = dispatch(getRequest());
    if (!!response) {
        dispatch(success());
    } else {
        dispatch(failure());
    }
};
```

In my `src/actions.spec.js`, I want to mock `getRequest` and simply return a json data, like:-

```
import * as actions from 'actions';


const mockReqResponse = async () => {
    return {data: '1123'};
};

const mockGetReq = jest.spyOn(actions, 'getRequest').mockImplementation(() => mockReqResponse);

describe('getBanks should work', async () => {
    const store = mockStore(); // mocked redux store
    await store.dispatch(action.getBanks());
})
```

The code flow does not reach to the mock implementation of `getRequest` which is `mockReqResponse`. Am I doing anything wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a common problem when testing thunks from the same module. You can either move `getRequest` to a separate module, or check the top answer to this question: [How to mock functions in the same module using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111198/how-to-mock-functions-in-the-same-module-using-jest) It's a bit weird but it works. This allows you to test thunks that depend on a couple of other thunks (or simple action creators) from the same module.