# jest.spyOn not calling mocked implementation but rather actual function instead

Tags: jestjs

I'm trying to write a unit test for a function that calls some helper functions in the same file. I'm using [jest.spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) to mock away those helper functions as it appears that it can do that.

**myModule.js**

```
export const getUserName = () => {
    return "mjordan"
}

export const getItem = () => {
    return 'basketball'
}

export const getUserWithItem = () => {
    const userName = getUserName()
    const item = getItem()
    
    return userName + " " + item
}
```

**myModule.test.js**

```
import * as myModule from 'path/to/module'

describe('getUserWithItem', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.restoreAllMocks()
    })

    it('Returns user with item', () => {
        jest.spyOn(myModule, 'getUserName').mockImplementation(() => 'tigerwoods')
        jest.spyOn(myModule, 'getItem').mockImplementation(() => 'golf ball')

        const result = myModule.getUserWithItem()

        expect(result).toEqual("tigerwoods golf ball")
    })
})
```

However, the `jest.spyOn` function does not appear to be mocking the implementation of the spied on functions but the test is calling the original functions instead which results in an output of `mjordan basketball` instead.

Am I missing something with how `spyOn` is supposed to work?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111198/how-to-mock-functions-in-the-same-module-using-jest/70066090#70066090

Comment: The framework offers the ability to mock and restore the mock in the same suite. It should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I have found to do what you want is to explicitly call the exported version of the function in your module, i.e.

```js
export const getUserName = () => {
    return "mjordan"
}

export const getItem = () => {
    return 'basketball'
}

export const getUserWithItem = () => {
    const userName = exports.getUserName()
    const item = exports.getItem()
    
    return userName + " " + item
}
```