# Jest spy toHaveBeenCalled not seeing function as being hit

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, spy, spyon

I am unit testing my JS file which consists of a lot of exported consts, with one of the functions calling some of the others held within the file, however I can't seem to get my test to see that it has done these calls - even though running the test with logging in the function to be called is triggered...

What am I doing wrong here?
I found some articles/questions and have tried what they suggest but it doesn't seem to be helping...

**MyFile.js**

```
export func1 = (arg1) => {
    console.log('inside func1');
    // Do something
}
// More funcs here

export mainFunc = (mainArg) => {
    func1(mainArg);

    // More stuff with other funcs
}
```

**test.spec.js**

```
import * as utils from './MyFile.js';

it('Should trigger func1', () => {
    const mySpy = jest.spyOn(utils, 'func1');

    utils.mainFun('something');

    expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('something');
});
```

When I run this test I will see `inside func1` logged out in my console, but I will also see that my test fails:

> expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
>
> Expected number of calls: >= 1
>
> Received number of calls:    0

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761. Fundamentally your `mainFunc` doesn't access `func1` via the module, but that's the wrong way to test it anyway.

Comment: @SamWillis I _did_, in the linked answer