# Is it possible to mock a free-standing function in Javascript with Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

There are many questions on StackOverflow about how to mock things with Jest. I have, indeed, read many of those suggestions. I have experience with `jest.mock` and `spyOn`.  I've tried the trick of doing a real import and overwriting just the function I desire to mock and have also tried the old `import * as math from './math.js'` and then you try to spyOn `math` but if you try it, you'll see that this won't work.

But after quite a lot of experimentation, I'm beginning to conclude that this is fundamentally impossible (which actually feels correct to me). The "real" subtract function that calls `add` will only ever be able to call the `add` defined in that module.

KEY POINT: The math.js file can NOT be edited. You cannot change it so that you have `add` and `subtract` as properties hanging off of some object.  Consider that the math.js file is etched in stone and cannot be modified in any way.

I would LOVE to be wrong about this, but it seems to me that the free-standing `add` function in the math.js file cannot be mocked such that when you call the "real" `subtract` function, it runs the mocked `add` function.  I know you could mock `add` and have mock `add` call a mocked `subtract`, but that is not the goal here.

Please consider this a purely academic question. This is not an XY problem. This is not a case of "what are you trying to do; there is a better way."  This is purely trying to understand how things work given the fixed constraints I've outline in the question. Thanks!

### math.js

```js
export function add(a, b) {
   return a+b;
}

export function subtract(a, b) {
   return add(a, -b);
}
```

### math.test.js

```js
import { subtract } from './math.js';

// mock the add function to return 1234

describe('math', () => {
   it('should return 1234', () => {
      expect(subtract(5,3)).toBe(1234);
   });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock functions in the same module using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111198/how-to-mock-functions-in-the-same-module-using-jest)

Comment: Specifically: [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761).

Comment: Kind of. Wasn't looking for a solution. My question was purely academic to ensure that scoping of module imports/exports worked as I believed they did. I've chosen the answer given by Necati Turan as accepted because he verifies what I believed to be true in his first sentence. The rest of the answer wasn't really necessary (for me); I was already aware of alternatives, but it may be helpful for future readers. Thanks to you both!

Comment: Hey, what happened to Necati Turan's answer?  I chose that as accepted answer, and now it appears to have disappeared.  Can we get that back please?