# How to mock a called function using jest?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, mocking

I am writing tests for functions in a file. Several functions call another function which is also in that file. Here is how it looks:

```
function importantFunc(str) {
  //some logic
  return result;
}

function funcA() {
  //some logic
  const result = importantFunc('test A')
  //some logic
}

function funcB() {
  //some logic
  const result = importantFunc('test B')
  //some logic
}
```

I have already written a test for `importantFunc`. Problem is how can I test mock the call to `importantFunc` in `funcA` and `funcB` so that they will not call `importantFunc` directly, but use the result I provide in my mock?

Between `jest.spyOn` and `jest.fn`, I am thinking `jest.fn` may work. But I cannot figure out how it will tie to `funcA` or `funcB`.

Comment: Specifically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111198/how-to-mock-functions-in-the-same-module-using-jest/70066090#70066090, which is to say: don't.

Answer (score 0):

You generally can't, unless if you're importing `importantFunc` from another module, in which case you mock the whole module.

What you *should do* is refactor your code so your units are not tightly coupled to one-another.

```
// in impl
function funcA(importantFunc) {
  //some logic
  const result = importantFunc('test A')
  //some logic
}

function funcB(importantFunc) {
  //some logic
  const result = importantFunc('test B')
  //some logic
}

// ...
// ...

// in test
const importantFunc = jest.fn(() => { ... });
funcB(importantFunc)
```