# How to mock a function from the same module as the function being tested

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

So, I have two methods on a Node project:

```js
export function methodA() {
  const response = await methodB();

  return response.length ? 'something' : 'else';
}

export function methodB() {
  const array = await getData(); // Access database and make API calls

  return array[];
}
```

`methodA` calls `methodB` and `methodB` makes stuff that I don't care right now for my unit testing purposes, so I want to mock `methodB` so it will return an empty array and won't try to make any database or API calls. The issue is that I can't actually mock `methodB`, as my test is still calling the actual function.
Here's my test:

```js
describe('method testing', () => {
  it('calls method', async () => {
    const response = await myModule.methodA();

    expect(response).toBe('else');
  });
});
```

That test is failing, because jest is still calling the actual `methodB` which is meant to fail, as it can't connect to the database or reach APIs, so, this is what I tried doing to mock `methodB`:

Spying on the method:

```js
import * as myModule from '@/domains/methods';

jest.spyOn(myModule, 'methodB').mockImplementation(() => [] as any);

// describe('method testing', () => {...
```

Mocking the entire file except for the `methodA`:

```js
jest.mock('@/domains/methods', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('@/domains/methods')
  return {
    ...originalModule,
    methodB: jest.fn().mockReturnValue([])
  }
});

// describe('method testing', () => {...
```

I have also tried:

- Mocking `methodB` inside each test and inside `describe`
- Spying `methodB` inside each test and inside `describe`
- Some variations of those examples I wrote above

I'm not entirely sure on what to do right now, so any light would be appreciated.

@Update: Altough the problem is similar, this is not a duplicate question and this ([How to mock functions in the same module using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111198/how-to-mock-functions-in-the-same-module-using-jest)) does not answer my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock functions in the same module using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111198/how-to-mock-functions-in-the-same-module-using-jest)

Comment: (Don't: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761)

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not.

Comment: Also, if you read my question and that answer very carefully, without much effort, you'll notice the "answer" there is of no help: `Trying to mock functions in the same module is like mocking parts of a class you're trying to test`.

That is true for most cases, but it's (and I say that with respect), ridiculous of you to assume THAT is an absolute answer for every use case. Every application has a different context and reasons behing it's structure. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Well you haven't provided that context and there are _ten other answers_ on the dupe that explain and hack around exactly the same problem. In what you've shown you should probably mock `getData` instead.