# Mocking method response with Jest spies and spying on node-fetch arguments

Tags: jestjs, node-fetch

I have one object (`ConvertkitServer`) that contains two methods: `addSubscriberTags()` that calls `getConvertkitTags()`. Both use `fetch()` and the scope of this question is limited to the tests I’m creating for `addSubscriberTags()`:

```js
import fetch, { RequestInit, Response } from "node-fetch";
// .. omitted for brevity

async function getConvertkitTags(): Promise<ConvertkitTag[]> {
  console.log('REAL getConvertkitTags()');
  // .. omitted for brevity
  console.log('REAL tags count', convertkit_tags.length);
  return convertkit_tags;
}

async function addSubscriberTags(email: string, tags: string[]): Promise<void> {
  const convertkit_tags = await getConvertkitTags();
  // .. omitted for brevity

  console.log('addSubscriberTags().tags.length = ', convertkit_tags.length);

  const response: Response = await fetch(
    new URL(`${CONVERTKIT_API_URI}/tags/${tag_ids[0]}/subscribe`).toString(),
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        api_secret: process.env.CONVERTKIT_API_SECRET as string,
        email: email,
        tags: tag_ids
      })
    }
  );

  return;
}

export {
  addSubscriberTags,
  getConvertkitTags
}
```

In my test, I want to:

1. force the return value of `getConvertKitTags()`; so I can
2. check for specific arguments used in the call to `fetch()` in the `addConvertkitTags()` method.

Neither is working.

- To handle (1), I’ve set up a spy to force a specific result. It should only return 2 items, but the console log statement from the mocked method is returning all 11. This tells me my spy isn’t working:

  ```js
  import * as ConvertkitServer from './convertkit.server';

  test.only('it adds 1 tag without throwing an error', async() => {
    expect.assertions(1);

    // setup SUT
    jest.spyOn(ConvertkitServer, 'getConvertkitTags').mockResolvedValue([
      CONVERTKIT_TAGS_RESPONSE.tags[0],
      CONVERTKIT_TAGS_RESPONSE.tags[1],
    ]);

    // run SUT
    const response = await ConvertkitServer.addSubscriberTags('test@test.com', [CONVERTKIT_TAGS_RESPONSE.tags[0].name]);

    // check
    expect(response).toBeUndefined();
  });
  ```

  ```
    console.log
      REAL getConvertkitTags()

        at CONVERTKIT_API_SECRET (contacts/convertkit.server.ts:195:20)

    console.log
      REAL tags count 11

        at getConvertkitTags (contacts/convertkit.server.ts:2598:11)

    console.log
      addSubscriberTags().tags.length =  11

        at Object.addSubscriberTags (contacts/convertkit.server.ts:2447:11)
  ```

  I don't understand why my spy seems to be ignored as the underlying one is what's being called from what I see in the console.
- Once that's fixed, I then need to test the arguments passed to `fetch()` within `addSubscriberTags()`, but after multiple attempts, I can't figure out how to properly spy on the `fetch()` method. I don't care if `fetch()` is called as I'm using MSW to intercept the calls. But I do want to check the arguments submitted, but all examples & questions/solutions I've found only address mocking `fetch()` which isn't what I want to do.

  I just want to spy on it and its arguments when called.

Comment: (**TL;DR**: [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761). Given you're using [MSW](https://mswjs.io/) assert on the request, not the arguments to `fetch`.)

Comment: I don't understand your comment @jonrsharpe... I _do_ want to check the params in the `fetch`. The argument `tags` is an array of strings & the method gets a collection of tags to convert that array into an array of numbers (`tag_ids`). I want to ensure that based on the array passed in, it submits the correct array of numbers to the endpoint.

There's more stuff going on that I removed to simplify the question.

Comment: The point is to, rather than `expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...)` (implementation), use the request object MSW exposes to assert on the path params, body, etc. (behaviour). Then you don't need to mock _any_ of what you're showing and can therefore freely and confidently refactor it.

Comment: Making sure I get this right... are you saying to test what `fetch` is sending, instead of testing fetch, test what MSW receives? So, effectively you ignore the headache of testing `fetch` and just look at what was received in the mocked response from MSW?

If so... an interesting approach. I'd need to figure out how the test can determine what MSW sent back for that specific test run...

Comment: Actually, not sure I get how that works... because now I'm spying on the MSW, not what my core is actually calling. For instance, other methods (not shown in this question) result in multiple `fetch` calls and I'd like to have tests that check those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an interesting one. It has got to do with the way you are exporting your functions. When you import these functions into another file, you are actually importing from the export object, which means you are not directly working with the original functions but rather with the export objects references. As a result, with spyOn when you are targeting 'getConvertkitTags' function, you are actually spying on export.getConvertkitTags, not the original function, reference of which was enclosed with the function declaration. This causes the mock not to take effect as expected. My brain is getting all jumbled up and doing a poor job in explaining. [here's](https://12ft.io/proxy?q=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2F%40DavideRama%2Fmock-spy-exported-functions-within-a-single-module-in-jest-cdf2b61af642) an article that explains this topic beautifuly. 
The only way I managed to make jest.spyOn to target the function properly was exporting them as arrow functions.

```js
// export from functions file
export const fun1 = ()=> 42
export const fun2 =()=> fun1()

// import in test file 
import * as jsMockery from ...
jest.spyOn(jsMockery, 'fun1').mockResolvedValue(42) // this works
.....
```

I hope we get some interesting suggestion from others.
p.s. from the comment i can see that there are other workarounds too. Still, seems a bit cumbersome to me tbh.

Comment: Any chance you've got an insight into the `fetch` question? Maybe I should have broken that into it's own question...

Comment: Great! And yes I think having a separate question is an excellent idea. If you do, feel free to drop a link here.