# How to properly mock exported functions from CommonJS modules using Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, commonjs

I have a CommonJS module that contains following exported functions:

```
// runFunctionalTests.js

const runFunctionalTests = async componentPath => {
    const componentPackageJson = getPackageJson(componentPath);
    // code
    await runTestsLocally(componentName);
};

const getPackageJson = componentPath => {
    // code
};

const runTestsLocally = async componentName => {
    // code
};

module.exports = {
    runFunctionalTests,
    getPackageJson,
    runTestsLocally,
};
```

My goal is to write a Jest test to verify that runFunctionalTests call invokes getPackageJson and runTestsLocally functions under the hood.

For now, I've ended with a partial mock attempt that obviously doesn't work:
Var 1

```
const fs = require('fs');
jest.mock('fs');

jest.mock('../runFunctionalTests', () => {
    const originalModule = jest.requireActual(
        '../runFunctionalTests'
    );
    return {
        __esModule: true,
        ...originalModule,
        getPackageJson: jest.fn(() => 42),
        runTestsLocally: jest.fn(() => 43)
    };
});

let {
    runFunctionalTests,
    getPackageJson,
    runTestsLocally
} = require('../runFunctionalTests');

describe('runFunctionalTests', () => {
    it('should call getPackageJson and runFunctionalTests', async () => {
        const packageJsonMock = JSON.stringify({
            name: 'TestComponent',
        });

        fs.readFileSync = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(packageJsonMock);
        fs.existsSync = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true);

        getPackageJson.mockReturnValue(true);
        runTestsLocally.mockReturnValue(true);

        const componentsToTest =
            'C:/src/components/test-component';
        await runFunctionalTests(componentsToTest);

        expect(getPackageJson).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(runTestsLocally).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Var 2

```
const fs = require('fs');
jest.mock('fs');
jest.mock('execa');

const sut = require('../runFunctionalTests');

describe('runFunctionalTests', () => {
    it('should call getPackageJson and runFunctionalTests', async () => {
        const packageJsonMock = JSON.stringify({
            name: 'TestComponent',
        });

        fs.readFileSync = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(packageJsonMock);
        fs.existsSync = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true);

        sut.getPackageJson = jest.fn();
        sut.runTestsLocally = jest.fn();

        const componentsToTest =
            'C:/src/components/test-component';
        await sut.runFunctionalTests(componentsToTest);

        expect(sut.getPackageJson).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(sut.runTestsLocally).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

I've tried to partially mock the *getPackageJson *and *runTestsLocally *functions, but they do not seem to be invoked, the code is running without mocks and both matchers are failing
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

```
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

I understand that my mock is not correct, but can't find an example how to properly rewrite it.
P.S. *fs* mocks that are needed for the other methods work fine, the issue is only with *getPackageJson* and *runTestsLocally*

Any suggestions?

Comment: (**TL;DR**: [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111198/how-to-mock-functions-in-the-same-module-using-jest/70066090#70066090). _"My goal is to write a Jest test to verify that runFunctionalTests call invokes getPackageJson and runTestsLocally functions under the hood"_ - that's not a good goal.)