# Issue when mocking functions that exist in the same file

Tags: jestjs

I'm writing tests for my TypeScript project and I'm having issues when mocking two functions in the same file.
This is my structure:

- `api-helper.ts`
- `api-helper.test.ts`

The functions `sendRequest` and `checkAccountActivatedByEmail` are inside `api-helper.ts`

This is my test:

```
describe('Test for api-helper.ts', () => {
  let context: Context;

  beforeEach(() => {
    context = {
      log: () => {},
      executionContext: {
        invocationId: '1',
      },
    } as unknown as Context;
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  test('checkAccountActivatedByEmail: valid and activated', async () => {
    // jest.mock('./api-helper', () => ({
    //   sendRequest: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
    //     status: 200,
    //     json: () => ({ id: 'xx', activated: true }),
    //   }),
    // }));

    jest.spyOn(utils, 'sendRequest').mockResolvedValue({
      status: 200,
      json: () => ({ id: 'xx', activated: true }),
    } as any);
    const resp = await utils.checkAccountActivatedByEmail(context, 'xx');
    expect(resp).toStrictEqual({ activatedByEmail: true, oktaId: 'xx' });
  });
});
```

The commented lines above are just to show you different ways I'm trying to mock it. Seeing the console I do realize `checkAccountActivatedByEmail` it's calling the real `sendRequest` function.

What am I doing wrong for the `sendRequest` not to be mocked?

I have already tried to mock in different ways and also mockImplementation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761