# Mocking one exported function inside one module

Tags: typescript, jestjs

Filename : Module.ts

```
export const functionName(...args){
    ...some code
    functionName1(...params)
    ...some code
}
```

```
export const functionName1(...args){
   ...some code
}
```

So these both the methods are inside module.ts file.

Now when I try to mock the whole file using jest like below

```
jest.mock('..path', () => { return { functionName1: jest.fn() } });
```

Will definately get an error saying that the function functionName is not defined on some import as i will be importing the statement like

`import * as Module from '../../module.ts'`

Does anyone has any idea about the solution or any workaround.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock functions in the same module using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111198/how-to-mock-functions-in-the-same-module-using-jest)

Comment: (**TL;DR**: [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761).)