# Mocking functions in module in project "type: module"

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, es6-modules

I have a project ES module (`package.json` with `"type": "module"`).
I need to make unit test on some functions of modules.
(code in JS but concretely my project is in TypeScript).

```js
// toto.js
export function main() {
    const res = a();

    return res;
}

export function a() {
    return 10;
}
```

```js
// test1.test.js
import { jest } from "@jest/globals";

jest.useFakeTimers();

// Erreur
jest.unstable_mockModule("./toto", () => ({
    ...import("./toto"),
    a: jest.fn(() => -2),
}));

// TypeError: main is not a function
//  > 53 |         expect(main()).toBe(-2);
jest.unstable_mockModule("./toto", () => {
    const totoModule = import("./toto");
    //console.log(totoModule.a);
    return {
        ...totoModule,
        a: jest.fn(() => -2),
    };
});
```

I tested Jest and it's not possible to mock. Jest supports partially for the moment, unit tests on ES module.
My example doesn't run because a Jest contributor said: *"You'll need to implement the entire mock manually within `unstable_mockModule` callback."*
It's not acceptable for me (too much work).

How do you make unit tests with ES module (other method, other package (Jasmine), return to CommonJS)?

Comment: You don't need to mock anything, `expect(main()).toBe(10)`.The fact that that's delegated to other functions _inside the module boundary_ is an implementation detail that your tests shouldn't have to know about. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761

Comment: Thx for your response. I'm reading your link. I must take time to understand. I would response then Jon.

Comment: Thx Jonrsharpe. I followed advices => dependency injection. Best practices for the future of my project. I'm alright to close this question, thx.