# Mocking one item in a module in jest tests

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, jest-fetch-mock

My goal is to mock foo, but not mock bar. This is a simplified example that demonstrates my issue, but I also have several other functions that i do NOT want to mock. I call the function bar from inside foo as shown below:

utils.js

```
const foo = async () => {
  const result = await bar();
  return result;
};

const bar = async () => {
  return 'THINGIMTRYINGTOMOCK';
};

module.exports = {
  foo,
  bar,
};
```

This is my file for utils.test.js

```
const { foo, bar } = require('../../utils');

jest
  .spyOn(require('../../utils'), 'bar')
  .mockResolvedValue('1234567890ABCDEF');

describe('who designed this shit', () => {
  test('test description', async () => {
    const result = await foo();
    expect(result).toBe('1234567890ABCDEF');
  });
});
```

However, this test fails, and the result is "THINGIMTRYINGTOMOCK", which means it's not being mocked correctly.

I also tried this alternative approach that I've seen posted on stack overflow for my test.js file, but I get the same result:

```
const { foo, bar } = require('../../utils');

jest.mock('../../utils', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('../../utils'),
  bar: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('1234567890ABCDEF'),
}));

describe('who designed this shit', () => {
  test('test description', async () => {
    const result = await foo();
    expect(result).toBe('1234567890ABCDEF');
  });
});
```

Comment: **TL;DR**: [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761).