# Trying to mock function using jest.spyOn but original function still being called

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I've been trying to mock a function using the spyOn method but it doesn't appear to work. Here is my test file:

```
describe('getValidUserIdList', () => {
  it('returns correct number of valid user IDs', async () => {
    const mockResponse = { statusCode: 200, body: { user: { is_private: false } } };
    const ig = jest.fn();
    ig['http'] = { full: jest.fn(() => mockResponse) };

    const getUserIdSpy = jest.spyOn(followers, 'getUserId').mockResolvedValue({ userId: '123', valid: true });
    await followers.getValidUserIdList(ig);
    expect(getUserIdSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(5);
  });
});
```

and here is the code I'm trying to test:

```
export async function getValidUserIdList(ig, numberOfIdsToGet = 5): Promise<string[]> {
  const userIds = [];
  let attempts = 0;
  while (userIds.length < numberOfIdsToGet && attempts < 50) {
    const { userId, valid } = await getUserId(ig);
    if (valid) userIds.push(userId);
    attempts++;
  }

  return userIds;
}

export async function getUserId(ig): Promise<{ userId: string; valid: boolean }> {
  const userIds = await getRandomPublicProfiles(1);
  const userId = userIds[0];
  const userInfoResponse = await ig.http.full({
    url: `api/v1/users/${userId}/info/`,
    throwHttpErrors: false,
  });

  let isUserIdValid = true;
  if (userInfoResponse.statusCode === 400) isUserIdValid = false;
  if (userInfoResponse.statusCode === 200 && userInfoResponse.body?.user?.is_private) isUserIdValid = false;

  return { userId, valid: isUserIdValid };
}
```

I've tried to mock part of the module and use some of the original like so:

```
jest.mock('./followers', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('./followers');

  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    getUserId: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ userId: '123', valid: true }),
  };
});
```

but that also didn't work.

Comment: **TL;DR**: [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761).