# How to mock a return value for a method called inside my testing target method? TypeScript and Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

Inside `loadUsage.ts`,

```
export async function readFile(filepath:string): Promise<any[]> {
   ........
}

export async function loadUsage(): Promise<MyUsage | undefined> {
   const data = await readFile('../filepath/');
   .....
}
```

I need to unit test the `loadUsage()` method, I would like to mock the return value of the `readFile()` method.

So far I have tried mock the entire `./loadUsage` like:

```
jest.mock('./loadUsage', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('./loadUsage');
  return {
    ...originalModule,
    readFile: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(mockData)),
  };
});



it('some test', async () => {
      ....
      (readFile as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValue(mockData);
      ....
   });
```

Or just spyOn the `readFile()` method

```
import * as loadUsageModule from './loadUsage';
jest.spyOn(loadUsageModule, 'readFile').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(mockData));
```

But when calling `loadUsage()` it still calls the read `readFile()` method.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock functions in the same module using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111198/how-to-mock-functions-in-the-same-module-using-jest)

Comment: **TL;DR**: [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761).