# Spying on hook not override the original functionality

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am having trouble mocking custom hook in Jest. See simplified code below.

```
// hooks.ts

export const useFoo = () => {
  return 1;
};
export const useBar = () => {
  const res = useFoo();

  return res;
}
```

```
// test.tsx

import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import * as hooks from '../hooks';

describe('hooks', () => {
  test('should return correct value', () => {
    jest.spyOn(hooks, 'useFoo').mockImplementation(() => 2);

    const { result } = renderHook(() => hooks.useBar());
  
    expect(result.current).toBe(2); // fails, because result.current is 1
  });
});
```

I am still getting number 1 as a result (not number 2), why?

Comment: **TL;DR**: [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761).