# jest.spyOn doesn't seem to mock default exported function correctly

Tags: jestjs, es6-modules

I can't seem to figure out why this test fails; I've reduced the problem to these 2 files:

```js
// esm-user.js

const getJack = () => {return 'Jack';};
const getJill = () => {return 'Jill';};
const getUsers = () => {return [getJack(), getJill()];};
export default { getUsers, getJack };
```

```js
// esm-user-spy.spec.js

import users from './esm-user';

describe("Mocks and Spies", () => {
  test.only("partial mock (jack)", () => {
    var getJackSpy = jest.spyOn(users, 'getJack').mockReturnValue('Mock Jack');
    expect(users.getUsers()).toEqual(['Mock Jack', 'Jill']);
  });
});
```

Output:

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
  Array [
-   "Mock Jack",
+   "Jack",
    "Jill",
  ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock functions in the same module using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111198/how-to-mock-functions-in-the-same-module-using-jest)

Comment: **TL;DR**: [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111198/how-to-mock-functions-in-the-same-module-using-jest/70066090#70066090).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getUsers` calls the function declaration `getJack` but you’re spying on the property `getJack` of the default export object and **replacing the value at that key of the default export** with your mock implementation.

`getUsers` in that file doesn’t call `getJack` on the default export object, it calls the `getJack` declaration in the file.

The below is one way to do it, for example (there are plenty of others), because the function you are mocking the implementation of is the same as what is being called in `getUsers`

```js
// esm-user.js
const internalApi = {
  getJack: () => 'Jack',
  getJill: () => 'Jill',
};

const getUsers = () => {
  return [internalApi.getJack(), internalApi.getJill()];
};

export default { getUsers, internalApi };
```

```js
// esm-user-spy.spec.js
import users from '../src/esm-user.js';

describe('Mocks and Spies', () => {
  it.only('partial mock (jack)', () => {
    var getJackSpy = jest
      .spyOn(users.internalApi, 'getJack')
      .mockReturnValue('Mock Jack');
    expect(users.getUsers()).toEqual(['Mock Jack', 'Jill']);
  });
});
```

### EDIT:

Perhaps the more common way to do this would be to just put `getJack` in a separate file and mocking it via jest.

```js
// esm-user.getJack.js
export const getJack = () => {return 'Jack';};

// esm-user.getJill.js
export const getJill = () => {return 'Jill';};

// esm-user.js
export const getUsers = () => {return [getJack(), getJill()];};

// esm-user-spy.spec.js
import { getUsers } from './esm-user';
import { getJack } from './esm-user.getJack';

jest.mock('./esm-user.getJack.js',() => ({
  __esModule:true,
  getJack: jest.fn()
})

// getJack is now a jest.fn, if you're using typescript you can do this:
const mockGetJack = jest.mocked(getJack);

describe("Mocks and Spies", () => {
  test.only("partial mock (jack)", () => {
    mockGetJack.mockReturnValue('Mock Jack');
    expect(getUsers()).toEqual(['Mock Jack', 'Jill']);
  });
});
```

Comment: makes sense; how would I spy on getJack()?

Comment: @RoyM - updated the answer. Are you using this just for learning purposes? The question seems contrived/non-practically useful.

Comment: By non-practically useful I don't mean the trivial implementations, I mean code is usually structured this way (as I alluded to with my naming) to hide internal implementation details from users of the module - effectively creating private methods. And you shouldn't be testing a modules private methods.

Comment: I did reduce the question to it's minimal form, so I can see why it would appear contrived. I must be missing the point of spyOn.. I expected it would be a non-intrusive way of seeing if something was called, but your answer seems to make me think otherwise. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @RoyM - Just curious did you add something to the default export so that you'd be able to test it? Or was `getJack` (or whatever it was in your case) always exported?

Comment: @RoyM you aren't missing the point of `spyOn`, you are misunderstanding how references work

Comment: I did modify it.. my original form was ```export const getJack = () => {return 'Jack';};
export const getJill = () => {return 'Jill';};
export default getUsers = () => {return [getJack(), getJill()];};
```

Comment: It can't be done with that structure, it could only be done in a test file if `getUsers` imported `getJack` from another file that jest could mock (or as I've shown above)