# How can I mock a function in jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to mock an api call inside a function here using jest. The idea is not to call the api, instead just mock the call, return some data and do the assert. It doesn't seem to work in the way I wanted. I looked at jest documentation for hours and still couldn't come to a conclusion.

```
const apiFunction = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to fetch data: ", error.response || error);
      return [];
    }
  }

  const dependencyFunction = async () => {
    const data = await apiFunction();
    return data;
  }
```

Test

```
import { dependencyFunction } from '../tests/utils';
import * as utils from '../tests/utils';

afterEach(() => {
  jest.restoreAllMocks();
});

jest.mock('../tests/utils', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('../tests/utils'),
  apiFunction: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(['data1', 'data2']),
}));


describe('dependency function', () => {
  it('should call apiFunction and return its results', async () => {
    const mockFunction = jest.spyOn(utils, 'apiFunction').mockResolvedValue(['data1', 'data2']);

    const result = await utils.dependencyFunction();

    expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(result).toEqual(['data1', 'data2']);
  });
});
```

My test is broken with the error Expected number of calls: >= 1 Received number of calls:    0. I'm bit confused here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not to completely contradict your idea, but you'd be better off if you 1.) don't mock the call, mock the API 2.) use Mock Service Workers (MSW) to achieve (1.). You'll achieve the same effect, in that your calls will need to return mocked data, but you won't have to worry about the implementation of your API to make it work (as long as it uses `fetch` under the hood you should be good; I would advise sticking to the 1.x version of MSW for now though.

Comment: Thanks Derek. I'm not too familiar with MSW. The requirement here for me is use only jest.mock. I'm bit lost.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock functions in the same module using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111198/how-to-mock-functions-in-the-same-module-using-jest)

Comment: **TL;DR**: [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761).