# mock work from the test file but not from the code file

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am trying to add unit tests to my JavaScript project using Jest, but I have a problem with the mocks.

The mocks are working when called from the test file but not when being called from the original code.

I'm trying to test a function `getDetails` from file named `httpClient.js`. This `getDetails` function called the `getAge` function I want to mock `getAge`.

When I debug this test, it looks like it knows that the mock exists.

I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: getAge is not defined

       7 |   getDetails(str) {
       8 |     console.log('got to getDetails()');
    >  9 |     return getAge();
         |     ^
      10 |   },
      11 |
      12 |   getAge() {
```

This is the original code:

```
const HttpClient =  {

  get(url) {
    return { id: 1, name: "John Doe", email: "john@example.com" };
  },

  getDetails(str) {
    console.log('got to getDetails()');
    return getAge();
  },

  getAge() {
    return '29';
  }
}
```

Test file code:

```
jest.mock('./httpClient', () => ({
  httpClient: {
    ...jest.requireActual('./httpClient.js'),
    getAge: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('25'),
  }
}));

const { httpClient } = require('./httpClient');

describe('fetchAndProcessUserData', () => {
  it('age should return 25', () => {

    const returnValue = httpClient.getDetails('not good');
    
    expect(returnValue).toBe('25');
  });
```

Comment: You need to add the reference of the object when calling the getAge method into it:
`return this.getAge();`. Adding `this` should solve the problem.

Comment: Nothing to do with the tests, your code is simply wrong. Don't mock parts of the thing you're supposed to be testing (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761).

Comment: This is a simpler code, I tried to make the problem more simple and understandable.
In my real case, i have an http.get() request instead of the getAge() function.
I can't make the mock for http.get work.