Mocking function from tested file is not working
I am trying to mock a function from a file which I try to test with Vitest.
test.ts:
export const bar = () => 'bar'
  
export const foo = () => `I am foo. bar is ${bar()}`

test.unit.spec.ts:
import { describe, expect, it, vi } from 'vitest'
import * as testFile from './test'

describe( 'module', () => {
  it( 'foo', () => {
    vi.spyOn(testFile, 'bar').mockImplementation(()  => 'fake bar')
    expect(testFile.foo()).toEqual('I am foo. bar is fake bar')
  })
})

When running the test, I get the following error:
AssertionError: expected 'I am foo. bar is bar' to deeply equal 'I am foo. bar is fake bar'
Expected: I am foo. bar is fake bar
Actual: I am foo. bar is bar

But whenever I put the variable bar into another file, it works fine.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761

@jonrsharpe I know about this answer, but I still want to do it

Well you can't anyway, foo doesn't access bar via that object so spying on it (as you've seen) does nothing.
