SpyOn function does not recognize call after click event
I want to write a unit test for the function renderSetupPage with Vitest. Somthing with the mocked function startGame seems to be wrong, but I can't find the error.
../scripts/utils.js:
export const renderSetupPage = (container) => {

  // create parent element
  const div = document.createElement("div")
  div.innerHTML = 
  `
  <label for="seed">Seed:</label>
  <input type="text" id="seed" name="seed">
  `

  // create button
  const button = document.createElement("button")
  button.id = "start-game-button"
  button.innerText = "Start Game"
  button.onclick = ()=> startGame()

  // append to parent
  div.appendChild(button)
  container.appendChild(div)
}

export const startGame = () => {
  window.alert("game started")
}

utils.test.js:
import { test, expect, vi, describe } from "vitest";
import * as utils from '../scripts/utils';
import {JSDOM} from "jsdom"

describe.only("that setup page is build correctly", ()=>{

    const dom = new JSDOM("<div id='container'></div>")
    global.document = dom.window.document
    const container = document.getElementById("container")

    utils.renderSetupPage(container)
    const button = container.getElementsByTagName("button")

    // passes
    test("that create button exists",() => {
        expect(button.length).toBe(1)
        expect(button[0].id).toBe("start-game-button")
    })
 
    // fails
    test("that button click starts game",()=>{

        const startGameSpy = vi.spyOn(utils, 'startGame').mockImplementation(()=>{})
        button[0].click()
        expect(startGameSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()

    })
})

The tests returns:
Error: AssertionError: expected "startGame" to be called at least once

which shouldn't be correct since a click in browser gives me the "Game started" alert.

The real implementation doesn't access startGame via the object you're spying on. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761

Thanks for your reply. This answer score seems to work! https://stackoverflow.com/a/47976589/4815096
